# How to make localStorage for all form inputs at once by form class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery script to make localsortage for all form inputs by form class . In this script I must define each input by his ID.

What I like to do is to make localsortage for all form inputs at once and if I add a new input in form I do not need to define it in the script.

```
<form name="local_storage_form" method="post" action="" class="">

    <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" class="localStore" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="your_surname" id="your_surname" class="localStore" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

function init() {

    if (localStorage["your_name"]) {
        $('#your_name').val(localStorage["your_name"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["your_surname"]) {
        $('#your_surname').val(localStorage["your_surname"]);
    }
}
$(document).on('keyup', ".localStore", function () {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});

init();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i did understand what you want.

This is the code that will fetch all the form input with the class localStore. And execute your logic for every single one.

```
function init() {

    $("form input.localStore").each(function(i,v){

        if($(v).attr("id")){
            if (localStorage[$(v).attr("id")]) {
                $(v).val(localStorage[$(v).attr("id")]);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

[Jquery.each() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)